# can anyone optimize my python code for "Pythagorean triplets"?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have written a code to find Pythagorean triplets but it is not optimized

it took 5-6 minutes for the algorithm to find answer for **big** numbers...
my teacher said it should take less than 3 secs...

```
num = int(input())

def main(n):
    for x in range(1, n):
        for y in range(1, x):
            for z in range(1, y):
                if x + y + z == n:
                    if x * x == y * y + z * z or y * y == x * x + z * z or z * z == x * x + y * y:
                        a = f'{z} {y} {x}'
                        print(a)
                        return

    else:
        print('Impossible')
```

for example if you enter 12, you'll get **3,4,5** 
if you enter 30 , the answer will be **5,12,13**

The sum of these three numbers must be equal to the number you entered.

can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Can the numbers be anything? e.g. is 10,1,2 also an option for 12?

Comment: You don't need to start at 1 for each loop. If `A^2 + B^2 = C^2` and `C > B > A`, then you can start at the next value for each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the proof for the [parametric representation of primitive pythagorean triples](https://archive.org/details/proofswithoutwor0000nels/page/134). In the proof, the author states:

[image]

We can use this proof to write an optimized algorithm:

```py
def p(num):
    a, b, c = 1, 1, 0
    n = 0

    while c < num:
        for m in range(1, n):
            a = 2 * m * n
            b = n ** 2 - m ** 2
            c = n ** 2 + m ** 2

            if c >= num:
                return "Impossible!"
            elif a + b + c == num:
                return b, a, c

        n = n + 1
```

```
print(p(12)) # >>> (3, 4, 5)
print(p(30)) # >>> (5, 12, 13)
print(p(31)) # >>> Impossible!
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of repeated and unnecessary work. You know that `A^2 + B^2 = C^2` and you know that `C > B > A`. It doesn't matter if you want to say `C > A > B` because any solution you find with that would be satisfied with `C > B > A`. For instance take 12 and solution 3, 4, 5. It doesn't actually matter if you say that `A=3` and `B=4` or `A=4` and `B=3`. Knowing this we can adjust the loops of each for loop.

`A` can go from `1` to `num`, that's fine. Technically it can go to a bit less since you are adding another value to it that has to be at least `1` as well.

`B` then can go from `A+1` to `num` since it needs to be greater than it.

So what about `C`? Well it doesnt' need to go from `1` since that's not possible. In fact we only care about `A + B + C = num`, so solve for `C` and you get `C = num - A - B`. That means you don't need to use a loop to find `C` since you can just solve for it. Knowing this you can do something like so:

```
In [142]: def find_triplet(num): 
 ...:     for a in range(1, num-1): 
 ...:         for b in range(a+1, num): 
 ...:             # A^2 + B^2 = C^2 
 ...:             # And A+B+C = N 
 ...:             c = num - a - b 
 ...:             if c > 0:
 ...:                 if a*a + b*b == c*c: 
 ...:                     print(f'{a} {b} {c}') 
 ...:             else: 
 ...:                 break 
 ...:                                                                                                                    

In [143]: find_triplet(30)                                                                                                   
5 12 13
```

So why check to see if `C` > 0 and break otherwise? Well, if you know `C = num - A - B` and you are incrementing `B`, then once `B` becomes too large, `C` is going to continue to get more and more negative. Because of that you can check if `C > 0` and if it's not, break out of that inner loop to have `A` increment and `B` reset.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you discussed takes O(n^3) complexity.

An efficient solution is to run two loops, where first loop runs from x = 1 to n/3, second loop runs from y = x+1 to n/2. In second loop, we check if (n – x – y) is equal to (x * x + y * y):

```
def pythagoreanTriplet(n): 

    # Considering triplets in  
    # sorted order. The value  
    # of first element in sorted  
    # triplet can be at-most n/3. 
    for x in range(1, int(n / 3) + 1):  

        # The value of second element  
        # must be less than equal to n/2 
        for y in range(x + 1,  
                       int(n / 2) + 1):  

            z = n - x - y 
            if (x * x + y * y == z * z):  
                print(x, " ", y, " ",  z)
                return

    print("Impossible") 

# Driver Code 
n = int(input())
pythagoreanTriplet(n)
```

**PS:** Time complexity = O(n^2)